# How to get a random int to change after the number is found

Tags: java

I am working on my final for class. I have managed to build most of it without having to ask for help but I am at a loss fr how to get the random int to change after the answer is found. I have tried moving the declaration inside the while loop but still get the same issue. When the user says yes the number does not change.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
          String choice = "y";
     int numberToGuess = (int)(Math.random() * 101);
    int counter = 0;
     System.out.println(
         "Welcome to the Guess the number Game");
     System.out.println(
         "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
     System.out.println();
     System.out.println(
         "I am thinking of a number from 1 to 100." );
    System.out.println(
         "Try to guess it.");

    while (!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
    {

        counter = counter + 1;
        int guessNumber = Validator.getInt(sc, "Enter Number: ", 0, 101);
        int guessVarience = guessNumber - numberToGuess;

        if (guessNumber == numberToGuess)
        {
            if ( counter <= 3)
            {
                    System.out.println(
                "Great work! You are a mathematical wizard");

            }
            else if (counter>3 && counter <= 7)
            {
                    System.out.println(
                    "Not to bad! You've got some potential");

            }
            else
            {
                    System.out.println(
                        "What took so long?");
                    System.out.println(
                        "Maybe you should take some lessons.");

            }

           counter = 0;
            System.out.println();
            choice = Validator.getString(sc, "Try again? (y/n): ");
            System.out.println();



            }


        else if (guessNumber < numberToGuess)
        {
            System.out.println(
                "Too Low!");
        }
        else if (guessVarience > 10)
        {
            System.out.println(
                "Way Too High!" );
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(
                "Too High!");




                }

            }       
        }
    }
```

Comment: You just need to find out an appropriate place to reinitialize the number which is being guessed, I think the answer is very obvious.

Comment: You should reassign a new random value when you want to try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another call to `numberToGuess = (int)(Math.random() * 101)`. You could do it immediately after determining they guessed correctly. Something like,

```
if (guessNumber == numberToGuess)
{
    numberToGuess = (int)(Math.random() * 101);
    // ...
```

Comment: That did not work. It still used the original number.

Comment: It works when I run it here, althoug it should really be `numberToGuess = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 100);` but I'd really prefer a `Random`.

Comment: I tried it again and it still uses the original number. I am not sure of why it works for you but not for me.

Comment: Got it thank you. Had to add it at the end with all of the other changes. adding it in the if statement would only work for that if. I thought I tried that earlier but my netBeans acts funny sometimes.